# How to disable Cash On Delivery for dokan vendors subscription

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, dokan

I am using WooCommerce Dokan (Version 3.2.6 ) multi-vendor plugin. In my website Cash on delivery and pay by card both methods are enable for users. But when any vendor purchasing a package, it is showing Cash On Delivey for that as well, due to which I have to keep track of every vendor manually whether he has paid or not.

> I want to disable COD for vendors and enable for users only.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just came across your question and decided to add the answer for future reference!

So, for disabling the `cash on delivery` option only for sellers/vendors not normal users, you could use:

- `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` filter hook.

And

- `dokan_is_user_seller` and `dokan_get_current_user_id` functions to check whether the buyer is a seller or a normal user!

Use the following code in your `functions.php` file:

```php
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'disabling_cod_for_sellers', 999);

function disabling_cod_for_sellers($available_payment_gateways)
{
    if (
        dokan_is_user_seller(dokan_get_current_user_id())
        &&
        isset($available_payment_gateways['cod'])
       ) 
    {
        unset($available_payment_gateways['cod']);
    }
    return $available_payment_gateways;
}
```

This answer has been tested on `Dokan 3.3.5`, `Woo 5.7` and works.